# Grid "dirty" flag not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I am having trouble manually setting/removing the "dirty flag" indicator on the Kendo grid control.

I have extended the tutorial to [preserve dirty indicators](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/preserve-the-dirty-indicator-in-incell-editing-and-client-operations) to include additional validation on the `value` field during the `dataSource.change` event:

1. A previously saved `value` (which contains an `id`) which has been modified to be 0 - this *is* a valid "dirty flag" (`e.items[0].id > 0 && e.items[0].value === 0`)
2. A `value` has been entered with a value greater than 0 - this *is* a valid "dirty flag" (`e.items[0].value > 0`)
3. Any other instance of `value` *is not* a valid "dirty flag" and therefore should be removed
4. If the user has left the `value` field "blank" i.e. "null", modify the value to 0 (`if (!e.items[0].value) {e.items[0].value = 0;}`)

With these changes applied, the `change` event now looks like:

```
change: function (e) {
    if (e.action == "itemchange") {                
        if ((e.items[0].id > 0 && e.items[0].value === 0) || e.items[0].value > 0) {
            e.items[0].dirtyFields = e.items[0].dirtyFields || {};
            e.items[0].dirtyFields[e.field] = true;
            _dirty = true;
        }
        else {
            if (!e.items[0].value) {
                e.items[0].value = 0;
            }
            e.items[0].dirty = false;
            e.items[0].dirtyFields = e.items[0].dirtyFields || {};
            e.items[0].dirtyFields[e.field] = false;
        }
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    }
}
```

Upon making these changes, I can see the `dirtyField` function (which is the `template` of the value column) being triggered, and can also see the appropriate `true`/`false` values being supplied and the appropriate return taking place (which, I thought, should set/remove the "dirty flag" from the appropriate cells):

```
function dirtyField(data, fieldName){
    if(data.dirty && data.dirtyFields[fieldName]){
        return "<span class='k-dirty'></span>"
    }
    else{
        return "";
    }
}
```

However, the "dirty flag" is not being removed until another cell within the grid is modified.

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ICIxUX/2) to demonstrate the issue. In order to replicate:

- Enter a value greater than 0 into the second row `value` cell (sets "dirty flag")
- Delete the value from the second row `value` cell ("dirty flag" remains -> should now be gone based on `change` event logic)
- Enter a value greater than 0 into the third row `value` cell (sets "dirty flag" on current cell, removes "dirty flag" from second row `value` cell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataSource.change` event is called before the grid cell is closed. So you refresh grid and cell changes are not properly reflected in the UI.

You should move grid refresh to grid `cellClose` event. Then grid refresh will be called after the cell is closed and everything works correctly.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    navigatable: true,
    height: 400,            
    columns: [
        { field: "value", title: "Value", editor: decimal_NumberEditor, format: '{0:n2}', attributes: { class: "editable-cell" }, template: "#=dirtyField(data,'value')# #:value#" }],
    editable: true,
    cellClose: function(e) {
        $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").refresh();
    }
});
```

Here is working example with events logging for better understangind of what's going on. See JS console:

http://dojo.telerik.com/ICIxUX/7

Comment: Thanks @sasha_gud, the demo works fine. For some reason though, I can't seem to trigger the `cellClose()` event on my grid definition.. Do you know if this is this a versioning issue(`cellClose` only available for specific version)/as a result of a conflicting grid attribute? **EDIT** Changed the version of controls on the demo you sent through to match my own and it is indeed to do with the version of controls.

Comment: It might be good to update your original question with the ultimate issue (versioning) and possibly indicate which version you were using that had the problem.